# How to compare two binary values in javascript/node js?

Tags: javascript, string, compare, comparison

I have two string

```
var a = "10001010";
var b = "10110010";
```

So What will be the function to find out Similarities in two string,
in that case that function will return this value;

A and B have 5 Digits in common; which are as below;

var a = "**10**001**010**";

var b = "**10**110**010**";

How can I get this values?

I need  similarities between this two strings.

Comment: Output should be in what format? indexes or the binary data?

Comment: What is the expected result and what you have tried till now?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Output should be in Binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)) `^` with the numerical values of the strings and value of 2<sup>8</sup> - 1.

In the binary result, a single `1` means same value of `a` and `b` and `0` means not.

> ```
>    value    binary  dec  comment
> --------  --------  ---  ---------------------------------------
>        a  10001010  138
>        b  10110010  178
> --------  --------  ---
>        ^  00111000   56  it shows only the changed values with 1
> 2^^8 - 1  11111111  255
> --------  --------  ---
>        ^  11000111  199  result with 1 for same value, 0 for not
> ```

```js
var a = parseInt("10001010", 2),
    b = parseInt("10110010", 2),
    result = (a ^ b) ^ (1 << 8) - 1;

console.log(result);
console.log(result.toString(2));
```

Comment: This seems very good. How's the efficiency of this kind of XOR operation. Imagine I'm comparing thousands in the same case.

Comment: it should go fast enough, it's just a binary operation.

Comment: Thanks! It's working normally without any noticeable overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can just compare them like this

```
("10001010" > "10110010") --> false
("10001010" < "10110010") --> true
("10001010" < "00110010") --> false
("00110010" == "00110010") --> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a logic to do this [enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/cetijarimo/edit?js,console)

```
var test = "10001010";
var test2  = "10110010";
var testArray = test.split('');
var testArray2 = test2.split('');
var resultArray = [];
for(index = 0; testArray.length > index;index++ ){
    if(testArray[index] === testArray2[index]){
     resultArray.push(testArray[index])
    }else{
      resultArray.push("*")
    }
}

console.log(resultArray.join(""));
```